# Visual Studio Extension: Get the path of the current selected file in the Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsx, vspackage

I'm trying to create my first extension for visual studio and so far I've been following this tutorial to get me started (http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2014/02/18/who-said-building-visual-studio-extensions-was-hard).
Now I have a custom menu item appearing when I click on a file in the solution explorer. 
What I need now for my small project is to get the path of the file selected in the solution explorer but I can't understand how can I do that.
Any help?

---------------------------- EDIT ------------------------------

As matze said, the answer is in the link I posted. I just didn't notice it when I wrote it.
In the meanwhile I also found another possible answer in this thread: [How to get the details of the selected item in solution explorer using vs package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194880/how-to-get-the-details-of-the-selected-item-in-solution-explorer-using-vs-packag)

where I found this code:

```
foreach (UIHierarchyItem selItem in selectedItems)
            {
                ProjectItem prjItem = selItem.Object as ProjectItem;
                string filePath = prjItem.Properties.Item("FullPath").Value.ToString();
                //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(selItem.Name + filePath);
                return filePath;
            }
```

So, here are two ways to get the path to the selected file(s) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article you mentioned already contains a solution for that.

Look for the `menuCommand_BeforeQueryStatus` method in the sample code. It uses the `IsSingleProjectItemSelection` method to obtain an `IVsHierarchy` object representing the project as well as the id of the selected item. It seems that you can safely cast the hierarchy to `IVsProject` and use it´s `GetMkDocument` function to query the item´s fullpath...

```
IVsHierarchy hierarchy = null;
uint itemid = VSConstants.VSITEMID_NIL;

if (IsSingleProjectItemSelection(out hierarchy, out itemid))
{
    IVsProject project;
    if ((project = hierarchy as IVsProject) != null)
    {
        string itemFullPath = null;
        project.GetMkDocument(itemid, out itemFullPath);
    }
}
```

I don´t want to copy the entire code from the article into this answer, but it might be of interest how the `IsSingleProjectItemSelection` function obtains the selected item; so I just add some notes instead which may guide into the right direction... The method uses the [`GetCurrentSelection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsmonitorselection.getcurrentselection.aspx) method of the global `IVsMonitorSelection` service to query to the current selected item.

Comment: you're right. I noticed this only a couple of days after. I've been doing it in the spare times so I completely forgot I even set up a class variable with that value.
I'm editing the question and adding another possible solution

Answer (score 6):

For future reference:

```
//In your async method load the DTE
var dte2 = await ServiceProvider.GetGlobalServiceAsync(typeof(SDTE)) as DTE2;
var selectedItems = dte2.SelectItems;
if(selectedItems.MultiSelect || selectedItems.Count > 1){ //Use either/or
     for(short i = 1; i <= selectedItems.Count; i++){
        //Get selected item
        var selectedItem = selectedItems[i];
        //Get associated project item (selectedItem.ProjectItem  
        //If selectedItem is a project, then selectedItem.ProjectItem will be null,
        //and selectedItem.Project will not be null.
        var projectItem = selectedItem.ProjectItem;
        //Get project for ProjectItem
        var project = projectItem.ContainingProject;
        // Or get project object if selectedItem is a project
        var sproject = selectedItem.Project;
        //Is selectedItem a physical folder?
        var isFolder = projectItem.Kind == EnvDTE.Constants.vsProjectItemKindPhysicalFolder;
        //Else, get item's folder
        var itemFolder = new FileInfo(projectItem.Properties.Item("FullPath").ToString()).Directory;
        //Find config file
        var configFiles itemFolder.GetFiles("web.config");
        var configfile = configFiles.length > 0 ? configFiles[0] : null;
        //Turn config file into ProjectItem object
        var configItem = dte2.solution.FindProjectItem(configFile.FullName);
        
     }
}
```

I hope someone finds this helpful...

Comment: What is GetGlobalServiceAsync? My ServiceProvider does not offer that method

Comment: Oh it's now just GetServiceAsync

Comment: This (and others mentioning how to access the DTE) were a start for me. However, in VS 2022 "ServiceProvider" was null (in the context of an item click handler). Random search at VSIX Community produced an alternative (maybe newest?) way: "AsyncPackage.GetGlobalService(typeof(SDTE)) as DTE2". From there got ActiveDocument.Name and .Path.

Comment: https://github.com/VsixCommunity/Community.VisualStudio.Toolkit/discussions/178