# Get selected items in solution with native interfaces

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, vsix

I am trying to get all selected items in a solution and this with native code. With native code I am referring to code which does not use the `DTE`.

I checked the documentation and tried to find a suitable solution, however I din't come very far. What I found was the [`IVsUiHierarchy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsuihierarchy?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) which contains the [`ExecCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsuihierarchy.execcommand?view=visualstudiosdk-2017#Microsoft_VisualStudio_Shell_Interop_IVsUIHierarchy_ExecCommand_System_UInt32_System_Guid__System_UInt32_System_UInt32_System_IntPtr_System_IntPtr_) method which contains the following.

> Commands that act on a specific item within the hierarchy. (If ItemID equals VSITEMID_SELECTION, the command is applied to the selected item or items.)

So I suspect the method they are talking about, is the before mentioned `ExecCommand` one. For one I am not quite sure how I will get to the `IVsHierarchy` object from a `IVsHierarchy` or similar, on the other hand I am not really sure on how to use the `ExecCommand` method properly. Additionally I am not even quite certain, if this is even the 'right way' of approaching this.

Note: I am searching for a solution which does not contain the following code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15406802/10070647).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [IVsMonitorSelection.GetCurrentSelection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsmonitorselection.getcurrentselection), to identify all the selected items in the solution explorer.

The above will return you an IVsMultItemSelect interface which you can use to invoke [IVsMultiItemSelect.GetSelectedItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsmultiitemselect.getselecteditems) to retrieve an array of VSITEMSELECTION values.

There are [a few extensibilty samples](https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/search?q=GetSelectedItems&unscoped_q=GetSelectedItems), that utilize GetSelectedItems, you can use as a reference.

Sincerely,
Ed Dore

Comment: Ed, you may want to update the blog URL in your profile to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vsx/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was digging for it for quite a while now. It works like a charm!